# get char out of uint64_t in c

Tags: c, char

so like title, im not sure how to get a char(in type "char", not just a byte but in the same type).For example, from a uint64_t?

I guess a type cast wont work?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does "not just a byte but in the same type" mean? It's best to show an example.

Comment: try reading [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, a `char` in C is only one byte, and therefore can mainly represent ASCII characters.
If you character is unicode, it simply cannot be converted to `char`.
If you do want to be able to be able to store unicode characters, you should use some other type, such as `wchar_t` (unicode, compiler-dependant size) or `char16_t` (utf16 character, can still not represent some characters such as emojis and other 4-byte characters), or even `char32_t`.

Either way, a simple cast should work, so far as you either use ASCII or unicode.

Note: Either way, the compiler will warn you that you may lose data in the proses, as `uint64_t` can store more values that existing characters and therefore is larger than any character type.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to get char value if your int64_t < 255 you can try casting it first to uint8_t like this :

```
printf("%c", (int8_t)var);
```

Else if you need every char in the uint64_t you can try :

```
void int64ToChar(char mesg[], int64_t num) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) mesg[i] = num >> (8-1-i)*8;
}
```

Comment: Why cast to `int8_t` vs. `char` as OP seems to want?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the character — or characters — got into the `uint64_t` value in the first place.

If you say

```
uint64_t uu = 0x41;
```

then `uu` contains the ASCII value of a single character, and it's trivial to pull it back out.  You don't even need a cast:

```
char c = uu;
printf("%c\n", c);      /* prints "A" */
```

Of course, since it's 64 bits wide, a `uint64_t` can theoretically have up to eight 8-bit ASCII characters jammed into it:

```
uu = 0x48656c6c6f;      /* "Hello" in hex */
```

If so, you can extract individual characters using some bit manipulation:

```
c = (uu >> 24) & 0xff;
printf("%c\n", c);      /* prints "e" */
```

Finally, since `uint64_t` is wider than 8 bits, it can also contain Unicode characters.  For example, I could write:

```
uu = 0x03A3;            /* U+03A3 Greek Capital Letter Sigma */
```

But now there's no way to extract that as a plain `char`, or print it using `%c`.  I'd have to use a `wchar_t`, and `%lc`:

```
wchar_t wc = uu;
printf("%lc\n", wc);    /* might print "Σ" */
```

Note that besides using `wchar_t` and `%lc`, this last works only if the output device is Unicode-capable, and if the "locale" is set up properly.

Theoretically we could cram up to four UTF-16-encoded Unicode characters, or two UTF-32-encoded characters, into a single `uint64_t` value, but that's getting increasingly speculative or whimsical if not downright crazy, so I'm not going to bother trying to demonstrate it.